# SAP Automation GUIShell - subtype Toolbar how to handle PressButton

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, sap-gui, findelement

I am new to automation, trying to automate SAP but stuck in handling  GuiShell (122) - SubType: Toolbar

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_COMPLETE_OIP:/SCWM/SAPLUI_DLV_PRD:2000/subSUB_OIP_DATA_AREA:" _
& "/SCWM/SAPLUI_DLV_PRD:2210/cntlCONTAINER_TB_OIP_1/shellcont/shell").pressButton "OK_REFRESH"
```

The element type is GuiShell (122) - SubType: Toolbar

I tried it declaring as GuiGridview, GuiToolbar, GuiButton, GuiTabstrip but object is returning as null. my script is not able to find this element.

Only getting/finding this element when it declared as GuiShell. But I am not seeing any method to click it.

Thanks in advance, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object returned by `session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/.../shell")` is null, then it means that it's not in the screen (i.e. not the right ID).

A shell object of type toolbar is an object of type [`GuiToolbarControl`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=GuiToolbarControl) (don't confuse with the object `GuiToolbar` which represents the "standard" and "application" toolbars which are at the top of all SAP GUI windows, or at the bottom of modal windows.

Comment: Thanks Sandra and what you said is the correct one, it was of type GuiToobarControl. I confused it with GuiToolbar.